# Slow site... but just in Chrome/Safari

Tags: html, joomla, performance

I'm trying to find a bug in a web application, which is causing Chrome and Safari to take up to 15 seconds to load the page (Firefox and IE, there are no problems). I've tried using Chrome's developer tools to find out what is causing the slowdown, but am unable to understand what elements/script is slowing down the page.

This is a joomla site with a custom add-on (done by another developer, not myself)... looking for some help in diagnosing the problem.

The URL is http://www.norfolktourism.ca/index.php?option=com_eventlist&view=eventlist&Itemid=70

Comment: Is it the custom add-on that does it? Have you tried turning it off?

Comment: What kind of hosting is this on? My Chrome Resources tab is showing A LOT of latency. (Check out Developer Tools -> Resources)

Comment: Well, the rest of the site works fine - but when you go to the pages that use the EVENTS module, that's when you see the slowdown.

Comment: Ryan - it's with a third party host - we're going to be transferring it to our local servers shortly.

Comment: If I could downvote my comment, I probably would. It can't really be the server because it works fine in browsers other than webkit.

Comment: Try to remove the addthis_widget.js script, it loads a lot of resources and it adds an hidden iframe that slows Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried loading the page with javascript disabled in chrome, and it's still super slow.  Using Chrome's developer tools, I see 25 messages showing "XML self-closing tag syntax used on . The tag will not be closed.", followed up by a "[ Exception: TypeError: Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got TypeError: Cannot read property 'ANY_TYPE' of undefined ]".

There do seem to be quite a few div tags that are self closing; while it *shouldn't* cause problems, it can't hurt to clean them up.

Comment: Other's have also had the problem reported; <div /> is apparently invalid - http://code.google.com/p/joomla-gcalendar/source/detail?r=822

Comment: Not to mention that XHTML is dying a slow death.  W3 is no longer evolving the spec: http://everythingisgray.com/2009/07/02/xhtml-is-dead-but-dont-worry/

Ok, so not dead, but it makes sense to go over to html 4.01 strict while we wait for html5 support....regardless, no more self-closing tags.  Woot!

Comment: Turns out that this was the problem. Somehow, a <div> was opened, and was never closed.

I love other people's code...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to try some chrome extensions:

- Firebug Lite: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/bmagokdooijbeehmkpknfglimnifench
- Speed Tracer: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ognampngfcbddbfemdapefohjiobgbdl

I think firebug is better than default chrome's developer tools. And speed tracer can be quite useful to track items that are taking too much time to load.

Answer (score 1):

Some advices:

1. Save the background image and every image that appers in the header in the png format to decrease their size
2. Try to enable the gzip because the html content weights too much
3. Use Chrome developers utilities to analyze every request that is done on the page to understand what is slow

**UPDATE:
Try to remove the addthis_widget.js script, it loads a lot of resources and it adds an hidden iframe that slows Chrome**

Comment: PNG format won't necessarily give you the lowest file size. Image optimization is more complicated than that, and while I don't completely understand it, I usually go by trial and error until I find the best compromise of file size and quality.

Comment: Doesn't JPEG usually compress better than PNG? Unless you can use PNG-8 and make them *really* small.

Comment: Yes you're right after that you must find a good compromise with size and quality, but i always prefer png because they preserve a good quality also with low size. Anyway the problem of the loading time is certainly caused by the size of the page.

Comment: If it's only happening on webkit based browsers like Safari and Chrome, it's probably _not_ caused by the size of the page.

Comment: Maybe with Chrome it's slower, but also with Firefox it's not fast. That site can be highly optimized and this can certainly improve its speed.

Comment: Sure, but the question specifically refers to the performance problems in Chrome and Safari.  Also, given that the performance problem only affects this page, it's likely to be something specific to this page.

Comment: I know that the images aren't optimized (I'm not the only who updates the website), but the issues aren't the image loading times.

As far as Chrome developer tools, all it will tell me is that "Layout" is taking an extended amount of time to execute.

Comment: Try to remove the addthis_widget.js script, it loads a lot of resources and it adds an hidden iframe that slows Chrome

Comment: Maybe that script is not optimized for Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Without showing us any code / script we can't really help much.
One thing I can recommend is begin with one panel and keep a dding to determine the root cause of this.

My instincts tells me it is the image loader as this may have some JS bug.  Top right corner remove that and try to load the page in chrome.  If you notice it is a lot quicker you know that is your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to trace the problem with help of DevTools Timeline.

[Timeline video guide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhaWYQ44WEc&feature=player_embedded)

[Other DevTools guides](http://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/devtools)

Some changes in Timeline UI happened after recording the video. 
As example all the top level events are collapsed by default.
But the idea is the same.

As I can see it is not a problem with JavaScript but with Layout recalculation.

Comment: The only information I can gather from this, is that Layout is what is causing the problem. I don't see any ways to get any further information on what exactly is the problem (or at least a ballpark idea).

Comment: Looks like a bug in renderer. Will try to nail it.

Comment: at least you can try to find the problem by commenting big sections of the page. If the problem goes away then it is in the excluded part of page. :)

Comment: looks like you have fixed it. :)